# Scraping text; I'm not sure the Google Chrome Inspect element is giving me the correct XPath. Where can I get the correct path?

Tags: python, html, xml, xpath, lxml

Here, I want to scrape a website called "fundsnetservices.com." Specifically, I want to grab the text below each program — it's about a paragraph's worth of text.

Using the Google Chrome Inspect method, I was able to pull this...

'/html/body/div[3]/div/div/div[1]/div/p[2]/text()'

... as the xpath. However, every time I print the text out, it returns [ ]. Why might this be?

```
response = urllib.request.urlopen('http://www.fundsnetservices.com/searchresult/30/International-Grants-&-Funders/18.html')
tree = etree.HTML(response.read().decode('utf-16'))
text = tree.xpath('/html/body/div[3]/div/div/div[1]/div/p[2]/text()')
```

Answer (score 1):

It seems your code returns whitespace nodes. Correct your XPath with :

```
//p[@class="tdclass"]/text()[3]
```

Comment: Is below the way in which I incorporate your revision? It's still not quite working for me: '/html/body/div[3]/div/div/div[1]/div/p[2]/text()//p[@class="tdclass"]/text()[3]' By the way, I also just realized that some of the text I want to access happens to be tail text.

Comment: No worries; I got the problem fixed! I realized how to use BeautifulSoup. :)

Comment: Nice. `tree.xpath('//p[@class="tdclass"]/text()[3]')` was just enough.:)